# SSRS Switch Sort

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

I have the following switch statement on a text box:

`=Switch(Fields!Column1.Value ="V10", "A", Fields!Column1.Value ="V2", "B", Fields!CColumn1.Value ="V7", "C")`

Then it has been sorted on `Fields!Column1.Value`.

When I run the report the data it shows like this.

- B
- C
- A

how can I sort the data so it show like this?

- A
- B
- C

Comment: Is this text box in a Tablix or a Matrix?

Comment: Hi, is a text box in a Tablix

Comment: @netraider what app are you using? SSRS 2008 r2?

Comment: can you please give some screenshots of your report table or tablix.

Comment: @netraider Use the switch expression as the sort expression in the Tablix

Answer (score 1):

You could create a calculated field on your DataSet to hold your `A`, `B`, and `C` values, then just show that calculated field on your report and sort by it.